Sending/Getting ID of Application Emojis in Discord.py
Can you not retrieve custom app emojis from the name alone?
Is there a way to fetch all application emojis and match the name to the ID?
I think someone asked this few years ago, but I haven't seen anything since.
get(bot.emojis, name=emoji_name)


This just retrieves matching emojis on the servers the bot's on, null if there's no match from a server.
Will await fetch_application_emojis() fix this? It's supposed to be out at 2.5.

Not sure if there's a way in discord.py but I just used this:
CUSTOM_EMOJIS = {}

async def fetch_application_emojis():
    global CUSTOM_EMOJIS
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/{app_id}/emojis", 
                               headers={f"Authorization": "Bot {app_secret}"}) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                emojis_response = await resp.json()
                emojis = emojis_response.get("items", [])
                CUSTOM_EMOJIS = {emoji['name']: int(emoji['id']) for emoji in emojis}

